# What can make an object non-transactional?

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, pojo

I am reading about JPA, when I came across POJO properties that makes it a jpa entity and one of the properties is "it should be transactional" which means -according to the book- : changes made to the database either succeed or fail atomically, so the persistent view of an entity should indeed be transactional.

And my question is : what in a java object might make it non transactional?

Comment: What is your book, what is page number? Can you quote more words?

Comment: dont use `@Transactional`

Answer (score 0):

> What can make an object non-transactional?

--> No using annotation `@Transactional` in Java POJO class.

Comment: but still it's a jpa entity and can be persisted and can be part of a transaction :) .... I think there's miscommunication

Comment: Now the author was talking about the properties that can make a normal POJO a jpa entity , so he said that it should be transactional (i.e. can be saved in a transaction) .... my question is : what can make a POJO non transactional , hence doesn't fit as a jpa entity ?